# React rails gem server side rendering issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I'd like to design email templates in react and render them in my rails application. I have installed `react-rails` gem and did the preliminary installation steps. i.e `rails g react:install`. I intend to use server-side rendering in a sidekiq-worker to send emails.
My config files are as follows:

`app/assests/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

`app/assests/javascripts/components.js`

```
//= require_tree ./components
```

`app/assests/javascripts/server_rendering.js`

```
//= require react-server
//= require react_ujs
//= require ./components
//
// By default, this file is loaded for server-side rendering.
// It should require your components and any dependencies.
```

`config/initializers/react_server_rendering.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# To render React components in production, precompile the server rendering manifest:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["server_rendering.js"]
```

`app/views/email_templates/send_welcome_email.html.erb`

```
<%= react_component('WelcomeEmail', { recipient: recipient, subject: subject }, {prerender: true}) %>
```

`app/javascript/components/WelcomeEmail.jsx`

```
function WelcomeEmail(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Our Website</h1>
      <p>Thank you for joining us. We're excited to have you on board.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WelcomeEmail;
```

I am currently first testing my code on the rails console with this:

```
 html_content = ApplicationController.render(
    template: 'email_templates/send_welcome_email',
    locals: { recipient: 'test@gmail.com', subject: 'Email' }
)
```

Without prerender I get this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Inflowkit</title>\n    <meta name=\"csrf-param\" content=\"authenticity_token\" />\n<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"xHEgcyuCHef276SxRiQyeBN+RrEWC4eXayEy8SESNZ2AwakabPdp1nvM/HPfEaiCsXHDFKgJZpqbQ+x8LfBieA==\" />\n    \n  </head>\n    <body class='main page'>\n<div data-react-class=\"WelcomeEmail\" data-react-props=\"{&quot;recipient&quot;:&quot;test@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;subject&quot;:&quot;subject&quot;}\" data-react-cache-id=\"WelcomeEmail-0\"></div>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

With prerender set to true I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from (irb):22
        4: from app/views/email_templates/send_welcome_email.html.erb:1
        3: from (execjs):1:40
        2: from (execjs):777:14
        1: from (execjs):579:13
ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: require is not a function)
```

if I add `//= require react` to `server_rendering.js` file i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from (irb):27
        4: from app/views/email_templates/send_welcome_email.html.erb:1
        3: from (execjs):1:40
        2: from (execjs):785:14
        1: from (execjs):37:13
ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'env'))
```

Could someone please help me get the set up correct?